# Given a circle of radius $3\rm{cm}$ inscribed in an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$ and $EZDU$ is a square inscribed in the circle.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Given a circle of radius $3\rm{cm}$ inscribed in an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$ and $EZDU$ is a square inscribed in the circle. Find the divsion of the area of the square divided by the area of the triangle. (Romania 1961)

> [image: g]

The area of the square is obvious from the radios of the circle. We have that $2ZE^2=36\implies ZE^2=18$ hence the area is $18$. This is where I got stuck. I don't know how to calculate the area of the triangle. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: Hint: $O$ is the centroid of the equilateral triangle.

Comment: @TonyIp I realized that, sorry for not having written it in the question, but I still don't know how to solve it

Comment: Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Actually, because you've tagged your question with contest-math, would you mind editing your question with where you've got this problem from?

Comment: @TonyIp sure thing

Comment: @TonyIp I don't have anything specific just the country and year

Comment: What country and year?

Comment: @coffeemath Romania 1961 the leaflet I have writes

Comment: I edited the question and wrote it there

Comment: Maybe you could use that $OC=2OD.$

Comment: @coffeemath yeah that's what Tony IP suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$O$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$
$\implies OC=2OD$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: nice one, forgot totally about that property. Yes, I can finish it off from here

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$\frac{S_{EZDU}}{S_{\triangle ABC}}$= $\frac{(3\sqrt 2)^2}{\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}{(6\sqrt 3)}^2}$=$\frac{2\sqrt 3}{9}$

[image]